# MERGE the results/list in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine my query results in nodes with different names, but in my next query, I want to search in the merged version of the previous result. How can I merge two lists or two set of nodes? As an example, imagine I have

(:class1)-->(c1:class2)-->(:class3)--(:class4)-->(c2:class2)

and then I would like to do a MATCH based on the distinct elements in the merge of c1.name and c2.name.

Comment: please describe more detailed and share what have you done. A vague answer to a vague question would be, if you want to use data from previous query in the next one, save the intermediate step to Neo4j.

Comment: @Tomaž Bratanič Sorry, I updated the description, I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The trick I learned somewhere to make this work is

```
MATCH (:class1)-->(c1:class2)-->(:class3)--(:class4)-->(c2:class2)
WITH collect(c1)+collect(c2) as nodez
UNWIND nodez as c
RETURN c
```

Note that you can't combine lists of different types (eg. nodes+relationships) this way. They have to all be the same type (eg. all nodes or all relationships). If you want to mix types in an aggregate list, you will need to convert everything to be the same type first (probably map).

Comment: if you `MATCH p1=(:class1)-->(c1:class2) MATCH p2=(:class2)-->(:class3) RETURN collect(p1)+collect(p2)`  then you will have both nodes and relationships

Comment: @digitalillusion That is a collection of paths, not a collection of nodes and relationships. I updated the note to more generally say you can't mix types in a list. If you really need to mix types, you will need to pack them in maps or something to make them all the same type.